# Janusgraph server complains Websocket Max frame length of 65536 has been exceeded

Tags: websocket, janusgraph, gremlin-server

I'm trying to load huge batch of data to janusgraph via a websocket connection from a go program.

Consistently I see this error.
Is there a configuration property on the janusgraph to increase this size?

```
1761394 [gremlin-server-worker-1] WARN  io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline  - An exceptionCaught() event was fired, and it reached at the tail of the pipeline. It usually means the last handler in the pipeline did not handle the exception.
io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.CorruptedWebSocketFrameException: Max frame length of 65536 has been exceeded.
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocket08FrameDecoder.protocolViolation(WebSocket08FrameDecoder.java:424)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocket08FrameDecoder.decode(WebSocket08FrameDecoder.java:286)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:507)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:446)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:722)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:658)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:584)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:496)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
```

Answer (score 2):

It is very well explained in this stackoverflow answer [Max frame length of 65536 has been exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57771803/max-frame-length-of-65536-has-been-exceeded)

Currently, my janusgraph server uses /etc/opt/janusgraph.janusgraph-server.yaml. `maxContentLength` by default is 65536. Setting it to higher values solves the issue.

```
host: 0.0.0.0
port: 8182
evaluationTimeout: 30000
channelizer: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.channel.WsAndHttpChannelizer
graphs:
  graph: /etc/opt/janusgraph/janusgraph.properties
scriptEngines:
.
.
.
maxInitialLineLength: 4096
maxHeaderSize: 8192
maxChunkSize: 8192
maxContentLength: 655360
maxAccumulationBufferComponents: 1024
resultIterationBatchSize: 64
writeBufferLowWaterMark: 32768
writeBufferHighWaterMark: 65536
threadPoolWorker: 1
gremlinPool: 8
```